# SQL Update with joins not working what am i missing here?

Tags: mysql

I don't know why keeps returning:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM vendas LEFT JOIN clientes c ON c.id = vendas.idCliente AND c.idRespons' at line 2`

**Mysql Query:**

```
UPDATE vendas 
FROM vendas
LEFT JOIN clientes c ON c.id = vendas.idCliente AND c.idResponsavel IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN funcionarios f ON f.id = c.idResponsavel
SET vendas.idVendedorResponsavel = f.id
WHERE vendas.idVendedorAtendente is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE vendas v

LEFT JOIN clientes c 
ON c.id = v.idCliente 
AND c.idResponsavel IS NOT NULL

LEFT JOIN funcionarios f 
ON f.id = c.idResponsavel

SET v.idVendedorResponsavel = f.id
WHERE v.idVendedorAtendente is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can leave the FROM vandas Clause like so

```
UPDATE vendas v
LEFT JOIN clientes c ON c.id = v.idCliente AND c.idResponsavel IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN funcionarios f ON f.id = c.idResponsavel
SET v.idVendedorResponsavel = f.id
WHERE v.idVendedorAtendente is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a from clause like this in a MySQL Update Query as stated in the UPDATE specification:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

I believe what you want is something like this:

```
UPDATE vendas LEFT JOIN clientes c ON c.id = vendas.idCliente AND c.idResponsavel IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN funcionarios f ON f.id = c.idResponsavel
SET vendas.idVendedorResponsavel = f.id
WHERE vendas.idVendedorAtendente is NULL
```